# How to call dispatch from onChange in react-router Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I am developing a web application where I want to use the URL query for running search queries.
When executing a search, a new request should be sent to the server to get new data, according to the url query params.
Using `react-router` and `Redux`, I want to call the `dispatch` function to fetch the new data from the server according to the query (i.e url change).

I was thinking to use the `onChange` event and call the `dispatch` function, like this:

```
<IndexRoute component={Catalog} onChange={(prevState, nextState, replace) => {dispatch(fetchProducts(nextState.location.search))}}/>
```

But since my routes is not a React component, I cant access the dispatch function.
I can import my store and use `store.dispatch`, but I read it is not recommended.
What would you suggest me to do?

Comment: why not use the `componentWillMount` React lifecycle method? you can access then to `this.props.params` and dispatch there whatever you may need.

Comment: Because I want to execute the dispatch on every search (I.e URL change). Dispatching the request results in a change in the store which affect the props of the `catalog` component, so using the `componentWillReceiveProps` results in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this kind of issues, we always declare or routes in a function similar to this:

```js
function createRoutes(store) {
  return {
    component: App,
    childRoutes: [
      // Here are defined the other routes.
      // They can be defined using plain objects:
      {path: "profile", component: Profile},
      // Or generated through a function call:
      ...require("./some/module")(store),
    ]
  }
}
```

When you do this it is fairly simple to use the store to dispatch an action or to do calculations in React Router lifecycle hooks.

```js
function createRoutes(store) {
  return {
    component: Settings,
    onEnter: (nextState, replace, callback) => {
      const state = store.getState()
      if (!state.user.logged) {
        dispatch(createNotification("You must be logged to perform this"))
        replace("/login")
      }

      callback()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did it just like that eventually. Just one more question, from the docs I couldn't understand what is the `callback`, what is it used for?

Comment: `callback` notifies that `onEnter` is complete. It is useful if you need to do async processing before committing the transition